# Find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2^x-1}x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Using L'Hopital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x\ln{2}}1$$
Which to me means it tends to $0$. Is this correct. The graph seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

> $$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x\ln a$$

So We have
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2^x-1}x=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2^x\ln{2}}1=\ln 2$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
By definition,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x-2^0}{x-0}=\frac{d}{dx}2^x\Big|_{x=0}$$